# Invalid resource directory name: "res animation" aapt.exe

Tags: c#, xamarin, compiler-errors, xamarin.android, android-animation

I`m using in visual studio 2017 and I keep having a trouble about this one, can you guys please help me, I already clean then rebuild it, but it always keep showing, thanks in advance. [image]

Comment: It is usually better to post any error messages as text, so they are searchable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rename the `animation` folder inside your `Resources` folder to `anim` and rebuild.